# Inconsistent Placement Of Signature/Initial Fields Given Identical Data and Visually Nearly Identical PDFs

Tags: docusignapi

We are experiencing an issue where, given two PDFs that are visually the same, and identical data, signature and initial fields being placed in unpredictably different locations.

[image]

We have created a Github repo that outlines this problem, contains both the good and bad PDFs, and sample code so you may reproduce this error yourself. The link is here: https://github.com/reside-eng/docusign-repro

What is particularly problematic is that, with the 'bad' PDF, the Sign/Initial fields are not all misplaced with the same offset.  If all fields were 20px off, we would not have a problem because we could change the placement offset ourselves.  However, the offset is unpredictable.

Comment: Your GitHub link seems to be wrong (I get a 404). Can you post a JSon of your example ?

Comment: Sorry the repo was private, its been made public.

Comment: When you say the PDFs are visually identical, are they actually identical ? Looking at your code, I can only speculate that either the PDF are slightly different or the variable input.top and input.left are different from a transaction to another

Comment: Your hypothesis is what I would expect too, however: 1) The variable input is the same, and the PDFs are indeed slightly different (one has contact info on it) HOWEVER, inputs are inconsistently placed. The PDF without data places all fields correctly, but in the PDF with data some inputs are placed correctly and some inputs are misaligned - *even on the same page*.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information that you have provided in the question. Definitely makes it easier to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Both your PDF's are in different resolutions.

So even though you specify the same tab positions in both the documents they will never be offset by the same value(relative to where you want the tab to be placed on the document) as the resolution of the page is different.

You will have to specify a separate set of X & Y values for the second document.

The following Tab values seem to place the tabs correctly. I have adjusted the X&Y values for tabs on documentId=2.

```
{
    "initialHereTabs": [
        {
            "documentId": "1",
            "pageNumber": "4",
            "scaleValue": "0.5",
            "xPosition": "374",
            "yPosition": "743"
        },
        {
            "documentId": "1",
            "pageNumber": "5",
            "scaleValue": "0.5",
            "xPosition": "289",
            "yPosition": "153"
        },
        {
            "documentId": "2",
            "pageNumber": "4",
            "scaleValue": "0.5",
            "xPosition": "374",
            "yPosition": "719"
        },
        {
            "documentId": "2",
            "pageNumber": "5",
            "scaleValue": "0.5",
            "xPosition": "291",
            "yPosition": "147"
        }
    ],
    "signHereTabs": [
        {
            "documentId": "1",
            "pageNumber": "5",
            "scaleValue": "0.5",
            "xPosition": "333",
            "yPosition": "158"
        },
        {
            "documentId": "1",
            "pageNumber": "5",
            "recipientId": "2",
            "scaleValue": "0.5",
            "xPosition": "69",
            "yPosition": "483"
        },
        {
            "documentId": "2",
            "pageNumber": "5",
            "scaleValue": "0.5",
            "xPosition": "334",
            "yPosition": "151"
        },
        {
            "documentId": "2",
            "pageNumber": "5",
            "scaleValue": "0.5",
            "xPosition": "76",
            "yPosition": "465"
        }
    ]
}
```